# When was MSTest introduced?

Tags: mstest

When was MSTest officially introduced? Was it out there before Visual Studio 2005? Could MSTest be used with VS2002/2003?

On [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSTest) it was very short and said created in Visual Studio 2005 but didn't seem official. I tried googling/binging deeper and couldn't find an exact answer.

Comment: Of course that Wikipedia article isn't official ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It came out with VS 2005.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364072%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)  I don't believe it would work with pre VS 2005 boxes.

However, you probably could use [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/)....

Comment: Ya I prefer NUnit, it's more out of curiosity and a debate among-est a few developers if it was a stand alone before VS 2005.